# Why is Clang's assembler output conditionally jumping to an unconditional jump?

Tags: c, macos, clang, code-generation, compiler-optimization

While debugging an issue with a program crashing on a mangled pointer being dereferenced, I ran `lldb` and did a disassembly of the crashing function. While perusing the disassembled code, I noticed this odd-looking choice of instructions:

> ```
> 0x100002b06 <+86>:   cmpl   $0x0, %eax
> 0x100002b09 <+89>:   je     0x100002b14
> 0x100002b0f <+95>:   jmp    0x10000330e
> 0x100002b14 <+100>:  jmp    0x100002c1d
> ```

I would expect the code to look like this instead:

> ```
> 0x100002b06 <+86>:   cmpl   $0x0, %eax
> 0x100002b09 <+89>:   je     0x100002c1d
> 0x100002b0f <+95>:   jmp    0x10000330e
> ```

I'm curious as to why Clang made this choice. Is it some sort of branch prediction optimization since this is a NULL pointer check that's very unlikely to match?

**edit:** [This is the originating C code,](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/blob/1f2fe4a0c1bca7486cfc5aa84877246e90d1321a/jdupes.c#L539-L543) specifically the line with the NULL pointer check.

```
traverse = travdone_head;
while (1) {
  if (traverse == NULL) nullptr("grokdir() traverse");
  /* Don't re-traverse directories we've already seen */
  if (inode == traverse->inode && device == traverse->device) {
```

Comment: Did your code was compiled in debug mode? If so, that could explain why the assembly code was written in this way.

Comment: It was compiled with `-O0 -g3`. It still seems a bit strange that it produced a jump to a jump, but that would probably explain it.

Comment: Since you added the tag C as well: what are the source lines that resulted in this code?

Comment: @RadLexus I've added the originating code with a little bit of extra context and a link to the original C file on Github if interested.

Answer (score 0):

`-O0` is for

> Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected
>   results. This is the default.

It could be interesting to compare with the according source code.